# Keep two Mica Powders separate in oil and water mixture

Tags: home-experiment, immiscibility

First off, apologies if this isn't the appropriate place to ask this, let me know and I'll remove immediately.

I recently acquired some Mica Powder Pigments, and they are fun the play with.  I mixed some with mineral oil, and some with water.  On there own, that's neat.  However, if I mix the oil and water (with powder suspended), the pigments tend to mix in the oil, reducing the contrast between the oil and water.

Is there some process I can do that will make one of the pigments hydrophobic and the other oleophobic?

Preferably with "household" items, or easily attainable items, in a DIY/hobbyist environment.